# Python - Polling a variable

Tags: python, signals, python-multithreading

I change a global variable in a signal handler and poll for it in the main program. But the value does not change in the main thread.

Is there a qualifier that I need to use to make it a volatile (like in Java) variable?

Here's the program:

**test.py**

```
import time
import signal

def debug():
    closeSession = False

    def sigint_handler(signal, frame):
        global closeSession

        print('Breaking the poll...')
        closeSession=True

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint_handler)

    # Start a program...

    while not closeSession:
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Polling... closeSession = %r' % closeSession)

    print('Exiting! Bye.')
    # Sent 'quit' to stdin of the program

if __name__ == "__main__":
    debug()
```

`sigint_handler()` gets called whenever I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> but the new value of `closeSession` is not used in the main thread.

I get the following output:

> $ python test.py
>  Polling... closeSession = False
>  Polling...
>   closeSession = False

*I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>*

> ^CBreaking the poll...
>  Polling... closeSession = False

*Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, again*

> ^CBreaking the poll...
>  Polling... closeSession = False

*Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, again*

> ^CBreaking the poll...
>  Polling... closeSession = False
>   Polling... closeSession = False

Comment: Very well formatted **first question**.

Comment: @MohitJain Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem is scope.**

Inside the `debug()` function, you didn't declare `closeSession` as a global, which means that you have two variables called `closeSession`. One global and one scoped within the `debug()` function. And inside the `sigint_handler()` function, you've explicitly instructed to use global one, which is shadowed by the scoped one in the outer function.

You can solve this by declaring global before assignment in `debug()`:

```
def debug():
    global closeSession
    closeSession = False
    ...
```

By the way, your code does not work on windows, it throws a IOError because the sleep function is interrupted. A workaround that worked for me is:

```
...
while not closeSession:
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
    except IOError:
        pass
    print('Polling... closeSession = %r' % closeSession)
...
```

It's not pretty but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `global closeSession` before accessing the variable, else you're creating a local variable with the same name and the loop will never end.

Try this:

```
import time
import signal

def debug():
    global closeSession # <-- this was missing
    closeSession = False

    def sigint_handler(signal, frame):
        global closeSession
        print('Breaking the poll...')
        closeSession=True

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint_handler)

    # Start a program...

    while not closeSession:
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Polling... closeSession = %r' % closeSession)

    print('Exiting! Bye.')
    # Sent 'quit' to stdin of the program

if __name__ == "__main__":
    debug()
```

Comment: The function was getting called on pressing Ctrl + C,
As "Breaking the poll..." was getting printed.

Comment: Aah :-) Sorry didn't get that. Did you try setting `global closeSession` before the assignment in `debug()`?

Comment: You are not actually using the signaling mechanism, you are simply calling the function explicitly.

Comment: @PaulCornelius That's what I already pointed out in a previous comment, the part with "sigint_handler() gets called whenever I press [Ctrl + C]" was added later.